# How best should I organize the action cards in Warhammer FRP 3e?

Tags: gm-preparation, wfrp-3e

I just got WFRP 3E. Mostly to play with my kids. That said, I bought a used set, and the cards were not organized in any way I could discern.

At present, the organization level is that I've pulled out just the basic action cards (that every character has access to) in order to verify that there were 4 players' worth, since the cards were in the PC boxes... The rest are in a bag.

***How best should I organize the action cards? Why?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aside for grouping Basic Actions together you should group:

- Melee Attacks
- Ranged Attacks
- Social Actions
- Spells
- Prayers

This way, when someone wants to create a melee oriented character with a dose of social interaction, he will only have to look through potentialy interesting cards. You can easily tell these categories by the nifty icon in the upper left corner, and there isn't really all that much of them in the first three categories.

Additionally, you should separate the spells and prayers by order and religion respectively, again putting the basic cards available to all wizards/priests aside, and sorting the other cards by rank. This way, when someone creates a new wizard/priest, he can easily see what actions are accessible to him immiedietly.

Comment: Done. And alphabetized within. But having the Pet Cards, they have the other symbols... a couple attacks, a couple socials...